# Prevent duplicated data in qfield

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have an issue with qfield. Is there any way to prevent creating duplicated data at each synchronisation with qgis. I would be very pleased if I get pertinent help.

Comment: I wonder if there is a common link with this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247953/qgis-offline-editing-creates-duplicates/247966#247966 I don't know the answer at the moment. I think it would be useful for you to provide some more details if you can.

Comment: Ok.what is happening, is that  every time I edit my features in qfield and when and i synchronize with qgis he duplicates existing features.

Comment: I want when I open my datas is qgis see only the new features recently added.